# ASP.Net Core 3.1 SelectList load wrong data from ViewData

Tags: visual-studio-2019, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to load a SelectList through ViewData. Previously, I have loaded ViewData["Almacenes"] with a List. But, when view is showed, there is not the expected data on SelectList. If I inspect the element in chrome, it shows me wrong data loaded. Could anyone please help me? I will really appreciate it. Thanks.

Repository

```
    public interface ISga_eDataService
    {
        public List<SelectListItem> GetAlmacenes();
    }
```

Controller

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
           ViewData["almacenes"] = _dataService.GetAlmacenes();
            return View();
        }
```

View

```
<div class="text-center">
    <span>Almacenes</span>
    <select id="Almacenes" asp-items="(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewData["almacenes"]" />
</div>
```

Inspecting SelectList in Chrome

```
<select id="Almacenes">








            © 2020 - Sga_eMinMaxChecker - Privacy


    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/site.js?v=4q1jwFhaPaZgr8WAUSrux6hAuh0XDg9kPS3xIVq36I0"></script>



</select>
```

Inmediate Window

```
?@ViewData["almacenes"]
Count = 32
    [0]: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem}
    [1]: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem}
    [2]: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem}
    [3]: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem}
    [4]: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem}
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution, but I still don't understand why the control behaved like that. So, if any could explain me why, I'll really appreciate it.

I have changed from

```
<select id="Almacenes" asp-items="(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewData["almacenes"]" />
```

To

```
<select id="Almacenes" asp-items="(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewData["almacenes"]"></select>
```

and it works.

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem, and I solve this with send ViewData to View as selectList.

you can use this in your Controller:

```
 var AlmacenesList = _dataService.GetAlmacenes();
 List<SelectListItem> Almacenes= new List<SelectListItem>();
 provinces.AddRange(AlmacenesList);
 ViewData["Almacenes"] = new SelectList(Almacenes, "Value", "Text");
```

and View:

```
<select asp-items="@(ViewData["Almacenes"] as SelectList)"></select>
```

Comment: The repository already returns a List<SelectListItem>. The problem was <select/> vs <select></select>.
Thanks for your answer.